# Source of Brecht quote, "I'm not trying to prove I'm right, but to find out whether", in Christie Malry

Tags: quote-source, bertolt-brecht, b-s-johnson

In the B. S. Johnson book *Christie Malry's Own Double Entry* there is a quote attributed to Bertolt Brecht saying

> I'm not trying to prove I'm right, but to find out whether.

I'm trying to find the source of this quote but my searches keep bringing up the B. S. Johnson book. Is this a real Brecht quote? If yes, where does it come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the quote comes from Brecht's play *[The Life of Galileo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Galileo)*. In Act 8, Galileo makes this remark, concerning his observations of sunspots:

> My intention is not to prove that I was right but to find out whether
> I was right.